# Se puede declarar una variable en un bloque y usar su valor en otro bloque? -Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, variables-globales

tengo una duda , es posible utilizar una variable en un bloque y después usar el valor de esa variable en otro bloque de script tipo las variables temporales de ASP MVC que se pueden usar en otro método o si existe alguna manera de guardar un valor temporalmente hasta que se requiera usar en alguna otra acción no necesariamente en el mismo bloque del script?

saludos.

Answer (score 0):

puedes declarar la variable fuera de los bloques:

```
var miVar = valor;
```

luego la usas en cualquier función

```
function a()
{
  alert('miVar'+ miVar ); //accedes a la variable global desde cualquier función.
}
```